# Aggregating data from file/array C++

Tags: c++

So basically I'm trying to come up with an algorithm to aggragate data (i.e combine items of same name from file, the file contains fruit name and fruit quantity next to it so i have to combine the quantity aswell).

So i have storeed all the info from the file onto an array and here is my algorithm so far: (The problem is that I know that this does not take into account items with more than two of the same fruit name, anybody got any suggestions I'd rlly appreciate it?

```
int aggregatedataA(items_t overallfruit[],items_t samefruit[], items_t uniquefruit[], int num){
int i, j, x=0, y=0;
    for(i=0; i<num; i++){
        for(j=0; j<num; j++){
            if(overallfruit[i].name==overallfruit[j].name){
                samefruit[x].name = overallfruit[i].name;
                samefruit[x].quantity = overallfruit[i].quantity + overallfruit[j].quantity;
                x++;
            }
                else{
                    uniquefruit[y].name = overallfruit[i].name;
                    uniquefruit[y].quantity = overallfruit[i].quantity;
                    y++;
                }

        }


    }
return x;
}
```

Comment: So, you basically just want a list of all fruit along with its total quantity, a list of fruit that shows up more then once, and a list of fruit that shows up only once? In any case, using a std::map comes to mind first.

Comment: I don't suppose using an `std::map<>` is an option? it would make this near-trivial.

Comment: Would std::map<> automatically sort out the data for me i.e combine the fruits with same name and add up their values?

Comment: @WhozCraig he [knows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18976343/85371)

Answer (score 3):

Use a `map<string, int>` to store all the fruits along with their quantity. Then find in this map fruits with quantity > 1 and copy them to , for example `vector<string>`. Then do the same with fruits with quantity = 1. For example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<map>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<functional>
#include<iterator>
#include<boost/bind.hpp>
#include<boost/ref.hpp>

using namespace std;

void same( vector<string> &vec, pair<string, int> pairObject)
{
        if( pairObject.second >1)
                vec.push_back(pairObject.first);
}

void uni( vector<string> &vec, pair<string, int> pairObject)
{
        if( pairObject.second  == 1)
                vec.push_back(pairObject.first);
}

int main()
{
        string af[8] = {"apple", "grape", "strewberry", "bannana", "mango", "papaya", "apple", "bannana"};
        vector<string> overallfruits(af,af+8);
        vector<string> samefruits;
        vector<string> uniquefruits;

        map<string, int> mfruits;

        for (int ix = 0; ix <overallfruits.size(); ++ix)
                 mfruits[overallfruits[ix]]++;

        for_each(mfruits.begin(), mfruits.end(), boost::bind(same, boost::ref(samefruits), _1));
        for_each(mfruits.begin(), mfruits.end(), boost::bind(uni, boost::ref(uniquefruits), _1));

        cout << "all: "; copy(overallfruits.begin(), overallfruits.end(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout," "));cout << endl;
        cout << "same: "; copy(samefruits.begin(), samefruits.end(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout," "));cout << endl;
        cout << "unique: "; copy(uniquefruits.begin(), uniquefruits.end(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout," "));cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: i want to basicaly make it so that theres only one item for each fruit kind and combine their quantites together im not sure what u meen by quantities>1 and quantity =1?

Comment: yes, maps will help you do that. map is like an array you can index with a string. you just check if the fruit has already been added to the map. if so you add your quantity, otherwise you add a new fruit.

Comment: Could u give me an xample please? say I have (apple 5, pear 3, grape 4, apple 3, pear 1) all stored in an array then I put on a map what do I do to sort out the data?

Answer (score 3):

**Update** Okay, my original answer here (see below) was somewhat joking.

So, here's a simple approach with just `vector`, `iostream` and `find_if`:

See it **[Live On IdeOne](http://ideone.com/HMsaVl)**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct entry {
    string name;
    unsigned quantity;
};

vector<entry> readData()
{
    vector<entry> data;

    string line, name;
    unsigned quantity;

    while (getline(cin, line) && 
            istringstream(line) >> name >> quantity)
    {
        auto found = find_if(begin(data), end(data), [&](entry const& a) { return a.name == name; });
        if (end(data) == found)
            data.push_back({name, quantity});
        else
            found->quantity += quantity;
    }
    return data;
}

int main()
{
    vector<entry> const data = readData();
    for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
        cout << it->name << " " << it->quantity << "\n";
}
```

---

OLD ANSWER:

Because it's been ridiculously long since the last question was posted in the [boost-spirit](/questions/tagged/boost-spirit) tag, lemme just take this opportunity to *over-kill* this answer:

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;
namespace phx   = boost::phoenix;

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, unsigned> data;
    std::cin.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

    {
        using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
        phrase_parse(
                boost::spirit::istream_iterator(std::cin), {},
                (as_string[+alpha] >> uint_) [ phx::ref(data)[_1] += _2 ] 
                % eol,
                blank);
    }

    std::cout << "Got #" << data.size() << " unique fruits\n";

    {
        using namespace boost::spirit::karma;
        std::cout << format(delimit(' ') [auto_] % eol, data);
    }
}
```

With input

```
apple 5
pear 2
grape 6
mangoes 3
apple 2
mangoes 9
```

Prints

```
Got #4 unique fruits
apple 7 
grape 6 
mangoes 12 
pear 2
```

Comment: -1: not everybody has 1000 years to wait for the code to compile.

Comment: @Fanael lol, but: `time clang++ -std=c++0x test.cpp -o test`: _real 0m3.320s, 
user 0m3.105s, sys 0m0.196s_

Comment: Even Coliru didn't die from exhaustion (this time): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59fbff5c25770fff

Comment: this looks nice enough for me to be tempted to finally get down and learn Spirit properly! BTW, what is the Fusion dependency here? Looks like it isn't being used explicitly!?

Comment: @TemplateRex It's implicitly used by the Karma rendering (it exposes a `std::pair` as a Fusion sequence so `karma::auto_` can automatically synthesize a suitable generator for the map elements magically.

Comment: Hm, that's a bit sloppy that the `karma` headers don't include the Fusion header themselves then

Comment: @TemplateRex how so? Cf. the first comment by \@Fanael

Comment: Ok thanks again @sehe but I dont understand what the bloomin 'eck is going on here tbh Im relatively new to programming still inexpereinced today is first time I heard about std::map let alone all this boost stuff. IS there any other simpilar way e.g an algorithm that would just use the typedef struct or could you explain ur code further plz man?

Comment: @Ossz _[eg. an algorithm](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc66943d8d4c5af8)_, this just uses the struct; The simpler way (IMO the simplest) with [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) would look like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc66943d8d4c5af8). Incidentally, those examples were in an answer to your previous question.

Comment: I hope it was clear that this answer is somewhat joking. I've updated the answer with a simple standard solution: **[http://ideone.com/HMsaVl](http://ideone.com/HMsaVl)**