# How should I use std::map<> to agregate/combine my data stored in array C++?

Tags: c++

So I have data of fruit name and corresponding quantity stored in a typedef struct array `overallfruit[].name` and `overallfruit[].quantity` and I know I have a certain number of arrays `NUM`;

How would I use `std::map<>` to aggregate the data i.e combine any fruits with the same name into one place and add their quantites together?

e.g stored in array

```
{apple 5
pear 2
grape 6
mangoes 3
apple 2
mangoes 9}
```

so I get

```
{apple 7
pear 2
grape 6
mangoes 12}
```

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke An array of structs (his old solution) or a map (the new solution he wants) can work. By the way maybe this link can be useful: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/

Comment: why is `mangoes` in plural :)

Answer (score 3):

There's the subtle issue of preserving ordering, which others have missed.

I present three approaches:

---

#### 1. Creating a new container

If you want to keep the order, you could do with a 'consolidate' function, e.g.

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc66943d8d4c5af8)

```
vector<entry> consolidate(vector<entry> const& in)
{
    vector<entry> result;

    for (auto& e : in)
    {
        auto found = find_if(begin(result), end(result), [&e](entry const& a) { return a.name == e.name; });
        if (end(result) == found)
            result.push_back(e);
        else
            found->quantity += e.quantity;
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

#### 2. *In-place consolidation* algorithm:

**[Live on Coliru](http://ideone.com/pa1Ycy)**

```
void consolidate(vector<entry>& data)
{
    auto f = data.begin(), l = data.end();
    while (f!=l)
    {
        auto match = find_if(begin(data), f, [&](entry const& a) { return a.name == f->name; });
        if (match != f)
        {
            match->quantity += f->quantity;
            f = data.erase(f);
            l = data.end();
        } else
        {
            f++;
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### 3. Using `map`

If you don't mind the order changing, use that map that was suggested in other answers:

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74505e2a85018279)

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct entry {
    string name;
    unsigned quantity;
};

int main()
{
    const entry array[] = {
        { "apple", 5 },
        { "pear",  2 },
        { "grape", 6 },
        { "mango", 3 },
        { "apple", 2 },
        { "mango", 9 },
    };

    map<string, unsigned> m;
    for (auto& e : array)
        m[e.name] += e.quantity;

    for (auto& e : m)
        cout << e.first << " " << e.second << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sehe but could u just explain a tad your bit towards the end? what i meant by e : array and i dont understand what m[e.name] += e.quantity is all about?

Comment: `e: array` is range-based for, disregard it. `m[e.name]` is the element accessor for the `std::map` and it will create a `0`-valued entry if it didn't exist for the key (`e.name`). `+=` is the _addition assignment operator_, so it adds `e.quantity` to the value of the map element.

Answer (score 2):

First create the map with `std::string` as key (the name), and `int` as data (the quantity). Then loop over the array, and for every entry add the quantity to the map as indexed by the name.

Comment: But keep in mind the result won't be in the order displayed in the question (see my answer)

Comment: @sehe Almost 11 am here, a little late for "morning" coffee, on the other hand the baby though it was a good idea for me to go up at 2 am so that might have something to do with it. :)

Comment: lol - Have another one. It's late for my morning coffee too. I should get one.

Answer (score -1):

Using std::map the index has to be unique, if you try and insert multiple pairs it does nothing.

For your question something like this should work:

```
std::map<string, int> fruits;
for(int i = 0; i<arraylenth; ++i) {
    fruits[overallfruit[i].name] += overallfruit[i].quantity; // add quantity to previous quantity if exists, or insert new map entry
}
```

Comment: You don't need the first branch, if missing the key is inserted and the value default-constructed ([ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)).

Answer (score -2):

I may not understand your question, but what I see is something like this:

```
std::map<std::string, unsigned int> fruitsMap;
for(std::size_t i = 0 ; i < NUM ; ++i) {
    std::map<std::string, unsigned int>::iterator it = fruitsMap.find(overallfruit[i].name);
    if(it == fruitsMap.end())
        fruitsMap[overallfruit[i].name] = overallfruit[i].quantity;
    else
        vIt->second += overallfruit[i].quantity;
}
```

It will traverse your array and fill the map according to your need.

Comment: why the branch? why the find? it's all unneeded.

Comment: They're unneeded only in that they will happen behind the scenes anyway. Don't go thinking you'll avoid find/branching; you'll only avoid doing it twice.